# How safe is Ubuntu's Release Upgrade feature for user tweaks?

Tags: upgrade, system, customization, do-release-upgrade

I need to install an Xubuntu system soon and will have to customise it to a certain extent, which means setting up a sound server with a specific configuration for the system hardware, remapping some keyboard keys with the xkb-files, setting up an encryptfs-folder inside the home-directory, installing Compiz and automatically place some windows in specific positions, etc. (These may not always be the most recommended solutions for any user, but I have found that a lot of those tweaks work best for me.)

Since I would like to install Xubuntu 17.10 now and upgrade to 18.04 later, instead of waiting or re-installing in a few months, I would like to know if those little custom tweaks to some system files, the user-directory and standard programs like the window manager will survive the release upgrade or if I'd have to redo some changes later?

How likely will the upgrade overwrite some of those settings and is there any way to control or figure out what's been changed? It would probably be worse if the upgrade breaks some program configuration and I am unable to identify the problem.

Does anyone have experiences with such non-standard installations and system upgrades?

Comment: Don't install 17.10 http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/12/ubuntu-corrupting-lenovo-laptop-bios

Comment: I didn't say I was installing it on a Lenovo laptop. In fact, none of that's the case, it's not a laptop and there's no Lenovo hardware in it.

Comment: Just wanted you to be aware of the problems.  Canonical has actually removed the 17.10 downloads till they fix it.

Comment: Well, thanks for the tip I suppose, I already read about the issue on the tech-channels. http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/17.10/release/HEADER.html works fine for me though and from what I've read so far, it's not only Canonical's issue to fix. Still, this doesn't really help with my question.

Comment: There is no way to predict the future or outcome of upgrades. In general, upgrades go fine, even with some customization, but "it depends" if such customization includes non standard repositories (ppa). Even with a standard install upgrades can fail due to any number of random factors. Back up your data and read the release notes before you upgrade.

Comment: Hi Panther, thanks. Could you elaborate you answer a little more? What does "even with a standard install upgrades can fail" mean? In the sense of a broken installation that won't boot because of data corruption? Or in what way will the *failed upgrade* be noticeable? Also, you wrote that if system tweaks survive or not  "depends if such customization includes non standard repositories (ppa)" - does that mean as long as I'm only using programs from the official repository I can be sure that they will remain as they were before the upgrade?

Comment: @Panther: I think you comment holds the answer to this question.

Comment: Release-upgrades are not the only time a customization might need to be maintained or preserved. Lower-level system services might change (sysvinit to Upstart to systemd). Hardware fails. Systems must be reinstalled. Keeping notes of your changes and improvements will help you troubleshoot, revert, maintain, and re-implement them.

Comment: @OrganicMarble -- that bug no longer applies. the driver has been fixed. There is even a fix for the computers that were affected by that bug.

Comment: Good news for the new year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to predict the future or outcome of upgrades. In general, upgrades go fine, even with some customization, but "it depends" if such customization includes non standard repositories (ppa) or other third party repositories.

Generally you disable all ppa and third party repos before you upgrade.

Even with a standard install upgrades can fail due to any number of random factors.

Similarly there is no guarantee any of your settings will keep with an upgrade due to any number of system or package changes.

Back up your data and read the release notes before you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. Although your answer is not exactly pleasant, I understand that the question was maybe a little broad in retrospect. Since I've already made a list of all my tweaks and back up all of my data regularly, I can reinstall my system within a few hours if need be, so I probably should take the safe route and not be lazy, if I want to be safe.